# Having issue with the Button

Tags: button, user-interface, blackberry

I made a **popup screen** in which there is an

> **EditField, and two ButtonField**.

Now i am facing very wierd problem there is two button one is `Cancel` and the other one is `Send button`. Now the first button i am adding is not working fine and the second button  working fine.For shake of simplicity in this code `Cancel button` will work and `Send button` won't. What i am missing here can anyone will help me .

```
ButtonField sendButton,cancelButton;
PinPopup()//Constructor
{
super(new HorizontalFieldManager());
texts=new EditField("","",200,Field.EDITABLE);
    sendButton = new ButtonField("  Send  ");
    sendButton.setChangeListener(this);

    cancelButton = new ButtonField("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setChangeListener(this);
        VerticalFieldManager _fieldManagerContext = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT)
        {

public void sublayout(int width,int height) {

                                super.sublayout(width, height);
                int xpos = 10; 
                int ypos = 40;
                Field field = getField(0);
                layoutChild(field, 280, 50);
                setPositionChild(field, xpos, ypos);
                Field field1 = getField(1);
                layoutChild(field1, 280, 50);
                setPositionChild(field1, xpos+10, ypos+80);
                Field field2 = getField(2);
                layoutChild(field2, 280, 50);
                setPositionChild(field2, xpos+145, ypos+80);
                setPosition(150, 220);
                setExtent(300, 220); 
}
public void paint(){
Overrided
}
_fieldManagerContext.add(texts);
_fieldManagerContext.add(sendButton);
_fieldManagerContext.add(cancelButton);
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{
```

if(field==cancelButton)
{
Dialog.inform("Cancel");
}

if(field){
Dialog.inform("Send");
}
}

**UPDATE**

```
if(field==sendButton){
Dialog.inform("Send");
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have tried this too but the same problem now guys what to do

```
cancelButton = new ButtonField("Cancel") {
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: With such messy code it will be difficult to get a nice answer.

Comment: @Arhimed i dont understand what is messy here in my code ...

Comment: To feel what I'm talking about just check blackberry questions of this guy - http://stackoverflow.com/users/165071/alexander-farber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i was getting because i am adding two button in a row, and i had used a VerticalFieldManager for adding the buttons that is why i got the problem. And for solution i have added the button in HorizontalFeildManager and now it is working fine

```
VerticalFieldManager _fieldManagerContext = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT)
```

to this one

```
HorizontalFieldManager _fieldManagerContext = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FieldChangeListener, for Send you are checking `if(field)` instead of `if(field == sendButton)`

Comment: sorry that was my mistake i have edited it wrong in real code i have written  **if(field == sendButton)**